# How to get a image either from a camera or gallery and display it on a different activity

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to take a picture either from a camera or gallery and then displaying it on a different activity.
Here is what i've done. It is working fine for choose from gallery but in the case of camera the app just crashes.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    private static final int FROM_CAMERA = 100;

    public ImageView imageView;
    Button b1,b2;
    private String imgPath;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b2.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class)));
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Button pickImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //openGallery();
                selectImage();
            }
        });
    }


    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(Main2Activity.this);
                String userChoosenTask;
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    public static class Utility {
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
        {
            int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();

                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_CAMERA);
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FROM_CAMERA)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }

    }

    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        /*Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);*/
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        String mFilePath = imageUri.toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra("image_path", mFilePath);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
          Uri imageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), thumbnail);
        //Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        String mFilePath = imageUri.toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra("image_path", mFilePath);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

I'm using Bundle to display it on a differnt activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            value = extras.getString("image_path");

        }        
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(value);
```

and then finally using the imageUri to display it.

Why is the camera part not working in my case?

Log

```
12-25 22:14:33.870 27023-27023/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-25 22:14:33.980 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.adobe.imageeditorui, real application class is com.adobe.imageeditorui.MainApplication.
12-25 22:14:33.980 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
12-25 22:14:34.050 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/AdobeImageCdsProvider: onCreate
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21330: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21332: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21336: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1060: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1082: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-25 22:14:34.190 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
12-25 22:14:34.210 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
12-25 22:14:34.210 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21917: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-25 22:14:34.210 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.290 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
12-25 22:14:34.290 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 718: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
12-25 22:14:34.290 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-25 22:14:34.310 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
12-25 22:14:34.310 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1023: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-25 22:14:34.310 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.310 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
12-25 22:14:34.310 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1025: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-25 22:14:34.310 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 22:14:34.320 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
12-25 22:14:34.320 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 224 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
12-25 22:14:34.320 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
12-25 22:14:34.380 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 531K, 25% free 2915K/3844K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
12-25 22:14:34.420 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/PGA: PgaGetGlTransport: Initializing transport = 0
12-25 22:14:34.420 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/PGA: Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 27023, tid = 27023
12-25 22:14:34.490 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui I/PGA: New SOCKET connection: com.adobe.imageeditorui (pid 27023, tid 27023)
12-25 22:14:34.520 27023-27023/com.adobe.imageeditorui D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: please provide your crash log here !!

Comment: I just posted my logcat.

Comment: I mean your crash log , select Error in your android monitor in Android Studio

Comment: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: you are not providing CAMERA permission in your utility class

Comment: what is the fix for this issue